# Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I cannot install app or build APK in android studio 3.1.4.  It continues showing this error:

> "Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.".

Here is my gradle below.

1. apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
       buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 27
           versionCode 6
           versionName "6.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           multiDexEnabled = true
           javaCompileOptions {
               annotationProcessorOptions {
                   includeCompileClasspath false
               }
           }
           lintOptions {
               checkReleaseBuilds false
               abortOnError false
           }

       }

       buildTypes {
           release {
               debuggable true
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }


   }

   // In the app build.gradle file


   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { //url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
           url 'https://maven.google.com'

       }
   }
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
       annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
       //compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-polly:2.3.8'
       implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
       //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
       implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
       implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
       implementation 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.2'
       implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
       implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
       //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
       implementation 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
   }


   dependencies {

       implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.4@aar') {
           transitive = true
       }


       implementation  'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.3'
       implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.6.1') {
           exclude group: 'android.arch.core'
           transitive = true
       }

       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
   {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
       // compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

   // fire base SDK gradle
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
       //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



       //implementation  'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71282'
       implementation  'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
       implementation  'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
       implementation  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
       implementation  'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
       //noinspection GradleCompatible
       implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
       implementation  'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation  'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
       implementation  'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
       implementation  'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
       implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'


   }
   ```

Comment: Improved readability + code formatting

Comment: what is the 'Messages' view?  I have searched every menu and submenu without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```